# How do I determine if the browser is 64-bit or not?

Tags: javascript, silverlight, browser

I have a Silverlight application I built back in 2009.  Unfortunately, Silverlight is not available for 64-bit browsers.  And the usage of 64-bit browsers is just starting to grow, especially with the release of Windows 8. So I want to detect the 64-bit browser and provide a user friendly message stating why the application was unable to load.

I could feasibly pull this off with a bit of Javascript, but the user-agents and such seem to be all over the map.  And I've tried `navigator.cpuClass` which seems to do what I want in Internet Explorer.  It returns `x86` on a 32-bit version of IE10.  But it returns `undefined` in Chrome and Firefox.  So I'm looking for a reliable solution for all browsers.

Note that **I don't care if the OS is 64-bit or not**. That doesn't matter. I'm only concerned about the browser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741933/detect-64-bit-or-32-bit-windows-from-user-agent-or-javascript

Comment: @lik2302 That shows the OS bits, not the browser bits.

Comment: so you are reffering to the edge case when the browser is 32-bit and the system 64-bit?

Comment: I haven't used plugins for a long time, but was it not always possible to display a fallback `html` inside of the `object`/`embed` element, like you can do with `noscript` if `js` is not active?

Comment: Instead of detecting the OS/browser, why not just detect the presence or lack of the actual silverlight plugin? Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119980/detect-via-javascript-whether-silverlight-is-installed

Comment: How do you want to handel this situation: Silverlight is not installed but browser is 32-bit ?

Comment: @faffaffaff - That's not good enough.  A user could have Silverlight installed (and it works on all of their 32-bit browsers they have installed).  But if the user is using a 64-bit browser, it's not accurate to say that it's not installed.

Comment: @luk2302 - That's for the OS, not the browser.  It's a different question.

Comment: @t.niese - Not sure what you're asking.  Here's the thing. 90% of the time the users at my site will be using 32-bit browsers which Silverlight can handle.  However, if a user comes along with a 64-bit browser they're presented with an unpleasant "Install Silverlight" user experience where they'll be directed to Microsoft's site only to be told that Silverlight doesn't work on 64-bit browsers.  I want to bypass all of that and do the detection of a 64-bit browser myself.

Comment: @t.niese - Oh, right now I get it.  Yeah, that situation is already handled.  They're simply instructed to install Silverlight if they're on a 32-bit browser but don't have Silverlight installed yet.

Comment: Please reopen.  The question marked as a duplicate is not a duplicate.

Comment: @SteveWortham check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6267019/1960455)  of the mentioned question.  Looks like the `window.navigator.platform` reflects if browser runs as `32` or `64` bit, so probably the question (even if not a duplicate) is still helpful.

Comment: @SteveWortham I have to agree with t.neise. The answer to this question appears to be in that answer. If that answer isn't correct, say so and I'll cast a repoen vote. EDIT: repeon vote? Zug Zug! I mean't a re-open vote :)

Comment: @corsiKa - That answer doesn't really answer my question any better than I already have.  I already knew that the `navigator.cpuClass` was effective in giving me what I needed for IE.  Their examples don't really help for the other browsers though.  I have a feeling that to solve this problem will require a lot of testing and looking at more than just the `navigator.platform` and `navigator.cpuClass` variables.

Comment: Umm, Silverlight 5 works fine on 64-bit browsers!  IE 9: http://i.imgur.com/fccYxu1.png and  [Pale Moon](http://www.palemoon.org/palemoon-x64.shtml) (64-bit Firefox): http://i.imgur.com/9jOGaIK.png  This is on Windows 7 SP1.  I'd assume it does on Windows 8, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - Interesting. I'm still trying to figure out why.  Is it possible that the rendering engine in these 64-bit browsers are actually running in 32-bit?  It obviously throws a wrinkle into this. But if you open IE10 from Windows 8 you'll get this message, "Microsoft Silverlight cannot be used in browsers running in 64 bit mode." at http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/get-started/install/default.aspx?reason=64bit

Comment: @SteveWortham: Are you using the desktop version of IE 10 or the metro one?  I don't think the metro one supports plugins.  They are 2 completely separate browsers.  On the "System Requirements" tab on that page, it says "Windows 8 Desktop" supports 64-bit in IE 10.

Comment: @SteveWortham: I think MS is lying.  http://i.imgur.com/m15dB6m.png  (p.s. the `*` in the table means "supports 64-bit mode")

Comment: @RocketHazmat - I'm using the metro one.  But I just found where it says 64-bit browser support is new to Silverlight 5... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg986857(v=vs.95).aspx  My app is in Silverlight 4, so it would appear that upgrading my app to Silverlight 5 would be one way to solve this.

Comment: @SteveWortham: Didn't realize Silverlight 4 didn't support 64-bit.  Upgrading is one solution. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @RocketHazmat, I uncovered that [64-bit browser support was introduced with Silverlight 5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg986857%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). My app was using Silverlight 4. So I upgraded to 5 and now it works with the 64-bit browsers I've tested.

However, there's still one exception. Even Silverlight 5 won't run in the metro version of IE10 under Windows 8. Apparently this is [by design](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13748496/102896) as this is a specialized version of IE10 optimized for touch. That still doesn't explain it for me though.  I think it's lame.

Of course this means that 64-bit browser detection isn't really a concern anymore.  Microsoft just needs to add Silverlight support to this browser and then I'll be happy.

UPDATE

I found an interesting tidbit related to the metro/modern IE10 in Win8.  You can instruct the browser that there are plugins on the page that [require the "desktop" version of IE](http://caioproiete.net/en/request-user-to-switch-to-desktop-version-of-internet-explorer-on-a-website/).

You just need to add this meta tag to your HTML...

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="requiresActiveX=true" />
```

And that'll generate this prompt...

[image]